# Redirect index.html to root with AWS s3 bucket (no htaccess)

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, dns

I have a simple, static webpage hosted in a AWS S3 bucket. S3 buckets do not support htaccess, as this is apparently an Apache feature.

I would like to redirect all `www.example.com/index.html` to simply `www.example.com`. Is there a way I can do this from my DNS management, or some other way I don't know about?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problem? the answers don't seem to match what you want. I also want to redirect from /index.html to just /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by enabling Static Web Site hosting feature in your S3 bucket properties. `index.html` is the default index document at the moment, so it will just work out of the box for you.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling Websitehosting for your S3 Bucket will do the trick. Doing so allows you to specify an index an error document.

see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html